# Solve the Cauchy-Riemann Equations for $u_x$ and $u_y$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know the Cauchy Riemann Equations in Polar Coordinates are as follows:

$$u_r= u_xcos\theta + u_ysin\theta$$
$$ u_\theta= -u_xrsin\theta + u_yrcos\theta$$

I need to solve the following equations for both $u_x$ and $u_y$.

I am looking for suggestions as to where to start. I have tried solving one equation for one of the variables and then putting that solution into the other equation and I also tried to divide the second equation by r but I have just gone in circles.

Answer (score 1):

So you have

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta \\-r\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\binom{u_x}{u_y}=\binom{u_r}{u_\theta}$$

The above matrix's determinant is $\;r\;$ , so its inverse is

$$\frac1r\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta&-\sin\theta \\r\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\implies\binom{u_x}{u_y}=\frac1r\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta&-\sin\theta \\r\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\binom{u_r}{u_\theta}$$

So, for example,

$$u_x=u_r\cos\theta-\frac1ru_\theta\sin\theta\;,\;\;\text{etc.}$$

Comment: Thank you.  I would have never put this in a matrix.

Comment: @AlyssaWallace Thank you. For some reason they teach us linear algebra before complex analysis. :)